# Identify whether a package contains GPL license

Tags: package, sha1, sha256

I have few thousands packages which contains GPL/APL/BSD license. Currently to identify whether a package contains a GPL license, I am iterating over each package looking for LICENCE file and then checking its contents and matching that with the sample GPL template. I am following heuristic that if matching is greater than 90% then it is GPL license.

```
 if match > 0.9: licence = True
```

But I don't think this is a correct way to do and also very slow.

So I was thinking, it is possible If I know the values of sha1sum, sha256sum values of all the files present in a package, can this help to identify whether package contains GPL license of not?

For example in my package sha1sum value for LICENCE is:

```
b7077bddb5a97beca2da00c07cc56b602e2ac6cc  LICENCE
```

So If content of LICENCE will same then the sha1sum value corresponding to it will be same? if thats true then I can identify LICENCE file with sha1sum value. Also Is there a another way to identify LICENCE file in a package?

Comment: If two files are equal, they will have equal hashes.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail @OliCharlesworth. What relation this has with GPL license

Comment: @Rahul That's something you should be able to answer for yourself.

Comment: This could be a good question to move to the http://opensource.stackexchange.com

Comment: As a side note, detecting licenses correctly is not entirely trivial. See https://github.com/nexB/scancode-toolkit or Fossology for tools that do just that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several versions of the GPL, so you would need to check for several of them. Also, some projects do not include the license/copyright file directly but instead say something to the affect of "This project is licensed under GPL v2". So you would find some, maybe even most, but not all of the projects using the GPL (or any other license).

Answer (score 0):

There is no relation at all. SHA-1 is a hash algorithm, which could be used for checking integrity of files or check whether file was tampered with. It doesn't describe information in any way (though, it's possible to use hashes to identify files, so if you know hash of GPL-licensed file, you can calculate hashsum of your file and compare it to see whether it matches).